# Define handlebars scripts in a separate directory

Tags: ember.js

I would like to avoid to manage a big index.html file containing all my handlebars template.
I read multiple blogs with different solutions but I'm not sure of the best one.
Is there someone from the official ember.js team able to provide the best practice for this ?
Is grunt the best solution ?

Currently I do not use any special backend like node.js. Only a basic http apache server. The REST API is provided by a Tomcat server

Comment: The core team is working to migrate from a ruby build system to something like grunt. What is your backend / server side setup? Can you use node /npm for your build step?

Comment: I've been using a variant of this example https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences, you can then link the output .js file in you index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO if you are not a rails developer then one of the best option would be indeed grunt or much better yeoman (http://yeoman.io/). Using the generator-ember (https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember) and yeoman togheter will get you up and running in no time. For example after installing yeoman and the generator-ember you can create a full project structure with a simple `yo ember`, this will create all the necessary folder for views/controller/routes/templates where you can start coding right away. You should give it a try.

**Edit**

As stated in the comment of @Toran Billups, the ember core team is working on this project (https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit) which will be grunt based and it will work using modules and much more awesome stuff.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have set up the yeoman system and I can run the "production" build of my demo app (grunt -build and grunt server commands are working)

Comment: I have set up the yeoman system and I can run the "production" build of my demo app (grunt -build and grunt server commands are working). It takes only 10 minutes to setup ! real time update of the browser (grunt server) is really a great improvements for me !!!