# Ember + Handlebars: how to extract templates from html code

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a rather simple Ember app, but even then there are already some 30 handlebars templates defined in the index.html file.

How can I extract these files from the html file and organize them identical to the models, controllers, routes, etc. script folders ?

At this moment, I do not want to pre-compile the templates (I understood Ember is not fully compatible with pre-compiled templates).  I just want to have the templates better organised (in a folder structure) so that further development and maintenance becomes less error prone ...

Hope somebody can give some tips.

**My index.html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<body>

    <!-- APPLICATION (always rendered) -->
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">
      <header>
        {{#linkTo 'publications'}}Publications{{/linkTo}} | {{#linkTo 'admin'}}Admin{{/linkTo}} | {{#linkTo 'about'}}About{{/linkTo}} | {{#linkTo 'login'}}Login{{/linkTo}}
         </header>
      <div class="row-fluid" id="applicationOutlet">
        {{outlet}}
      </div>
    </script>

    <!-- ADMIN -->
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="admin">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
          Select a function <br />
          <ul>
            <li>{{#linkTo 'categories'}}Categories{{/linkTo}}</li>
            <li>{{#linkTo 'authors'}}Authors{{/linkTo}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="span9" id="adminOutlet">
          {{outlet}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>

    <!-- ADMIN/AUTHORS -->
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="authors">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
          Authors ({{numberOfAuthors}})<br />
          <table>
          {{#each author in content}}
            <tr><td>{{#linkTo 'authors.show' author}}{{author.name}}{{/linkTo}}</td></tr>
          {{else}}
            <tr><td>No authors defined</td></tr>
          {{/each}}
          </table>
          <br />
          {{#linkTo 'authors.new'}}New author{{/linkTo}}
        </div>
        <div class="span6" id="authorsOutlet">
          {{outlet}}
        </div> 
      </div>
    </script>

    <!--called when no nested author is selected-->
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="authors/index">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9">
          Select an author or create a new one
        </div> 
      </div>
    </script>

......


 <!-- SCRIPTS -->   
    <!--Libraries-->
    <script src="scripts/libraries/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/libraries/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/libraries/moment.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/libraries/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/libraries/showdown.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/libraries/ember-1.0.0-rc.6.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/libraries/ember-data.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/libraries/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!--Application-->
    <script src="scripts/application/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/application/router.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/application/store.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!--Routes-->
    <script src="scripts/routes/login_route.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/routes/about_route.js"></script>
    <!--Routes: admin-->
    <script src="scripts/routes/admin/admin_route.js"></script>
    <!--Routes: admin/authors-->  
    <script src="scripts/routes/admin/authors/authors_show_route.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/routes/admin/authors/authors_route.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/routes/admin/authors/authors_new_route.js"></script>
```

thanks
Marc

Comment: Can you show what code you do have and what you have tried?

Comment: I have added a part of the html. You will see that all handlebars templates are just in the index.html.  All other script files are referenced via the appropriate <script> tags.  As the handlebars syntax is html, I cannot simply include them in a .js file ...  I would need something else to reference in index.html the various templates ...  Hope you can help.

Comment: have a look at this answer, it is maybe what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028066/define-handlebars-scripts-in-a-separate-directory/18028112#18028112

Comment: @intuitivepixel I am rather new to Ember and was hoping that I could simply move the handlebars templates to a file on disk and then reference them in the index.html. At this stage I wanted to prevent the use of another set of libraries or tools such as Require.js or Ember app kit ... is there a way to store the handlebars templates as hbs files and then reference them in the index.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom resolver to load the templates on demand. This will work fine for development purposes. The main caveat is the template loading is `synchronous`. Your page will block while the template is being fetched.

The below `Resolver` loads templates from the `templates` folder. You will need to mirror your file structure to correspond to the `data-template-name` or `id` of the templates in your html.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  resolver: Ember.DefaultResolver.extend({
    resolveTemplate: function (parsedName) {
      var template = this._super(parsedName);

      if (!template) {
        var templateName = parsedName.fullNameWithoutType.replace(/\./g, "/"),
        filePath = "templates/" + templateName + ".js";

        $.ajax({
          url: filePath,
          async: false,
          dataType: "script"
        });

        template = this._super(parsedName);
      }

      return template;
    }
  })
});
```

This code is from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mekishizufu/5727982). For more a detailed discussion about it see this [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2742).

Note: just setting async to true won't work since template lookup is `synchronous`.

Comment: This works very well !  Only disadvantage is that you also need to provide separate ".index" template files.  If such an ".index" template is not found in the index.html file, the resolver tries to load it via Ajax and if missing then error 404 ...